# How can I store the hierarchic Authority Class in the Person Class?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-spring-security

my question is: (How?) can I store my "authority" for my user in the user class in Grails with the Spring Security Plugin?

I've given the following SQL structure:

User table:

```
...
varchar(255): username
...
int(2) rank: (refers to Rank table)
```

Rank table:

```
int(11): id
varchar(25): rank_name
```

Can I configure my domain classes, to work with that structure instead of the typical "User, Authority, UserAuthority many to many" schema?

The rank (id) is hierarchial, that means a user with the rank 4 got all "authorities" from a user with rank 3 etc.

EDIT:
I simply replaced in the User Domain, the getAuthorities method with the following:

```
Set<Permission> getAuthorities() {
    Authority.findAllById(this.rank)
    // instead of: UserAuthority.findAllByUser(this)*.permission
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [GormUserDetailsService](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/userdetails/GormUserDetailsService.groovy#L82) to see how authorites are loaded.
There's an `authoritiesPropertyName` configuration for springsecurity core, which specifies the property name of user domain which should return the authorities, the default value is 'authorities' -- you can modify this to return the authorities based on your domain model.

If this does not satisfy your requirement then You can create a custom user details service too.

And override the original user details service by defining a bean with name `userDetailsService` in your `conf/spring/resources.groovy`